# Track how much a user downloads / month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Id like to track individual users download statistics, im using the Ruby on Rails plugin paperclip to handle uploads and the files are stored on a local server, im not using S3.

Each file is given a unique name that is 26 characters long, which belongs to a user, so no matter who downloads that file the GB's downloaded will be taken from the corresponding users account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends where you are storing your files. If they are in `public` directory, then when somebody requests it, it doesn't go through Rails stack, so the only way here is to read server logs, or in general it depends on server you are using and there you should look for answer for your question.

Otherwise, if you serve files through controller, then during processing in controller you should know which user is making this request and which file is being requested. Then you can store each download request in special table with fields like this: `user_id, file_id, file_size` or something similar, or just add some value to a field in user model, for example to `total_downloads` field. First solution is better, because you know exactly what files were downloaded and when.

Of course you will not know if user stoped downloading a file and it will account whole file size at the begining of download.

Comment: I strongly recommend sending the file via the controller so that you have more control over the process, as klew alluded to.